# D/AudioTrack: start(): 0x76f579ed00 spam

Tags: java, android, audiotrack

On google I could't find what I need so I am here.
When I start my app on a phone and check the Logcat this gets spammed:

> D/AudioTrack: start(): 0x76f579ed00

this is about every 100ms and it only stops when I close the app or somehow this happens:

> D/AudioTrackShared: this(0x76fb539fa0), mCblk(0x76cf003000), front(1441728), mIsOut 1, interrupt() FUTEX_WAKE

I think this could block the CPU with useless load so I want to get it away if possible.
On google I could't find what I need so I am here.
As I  don't realy know what causes this problem so just ask for data you need.

Comment: sometimes firmware developers forget to remove their logs. For me it looks like they forgot to remove logging from inside `AudioTrack` class. There is not much you can do about it. Try on other device, if you worry about if this is a problem. I think that on the other device there will be no logs like this.

Comment: So basically harmless

Comment: yes, that's what I think. If you want to be sure - check on other device, or try using the performance profiler to check if your app does some unexpected load on CPU, etc

Comment: Yes, it's harmless and its probably device specific